# Anaconda Powershell Prompt not exporting environment to .yml file

Tags: powershell, anaconda, export, environment, prompt

I'm trying to create a new environment from file, when i run `conda env export > environment.yml` the file is created but when running `vim environment.yml` i get this error
**vim : The term 'vim' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

when trying to run  `conda env create --prefix .\env -f ..\environment.yml` on my new project directory i get **An unexpected error has occurred.**

Comment: _when i run conda env export > environment.yml the file is created but when running vim environment.yml i get this error vim : The term 'vim' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again._ Doesn't that indicate that the issue isn't with exporting the environment.yml file? _on my new project directory i get An unexpected error has occurred._ Can you run it again after increasing the verbosity, so that we can get more information?